# Activity result code always 0 (cancel) when there is two or more activities to handle intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a problem, when I startActivityForResult to take picure, resultCode is always Activity.RESULT_CANCELED (0) if there is two or more camera apps that can handle that intent (app chooser appears). But if I set one of them as default app and next time it doesn't offer me a chooser, everything works fine, and it takes picture and detects it in a onActivityResult in my fragment that started startActivityForResult().
Same thing happens when I try to open gallery to select picture. If there are two gallery apps, I choose either one of them, picture selection result is always 0.
This is the code I use to start camera app:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
      startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, AppConstants.TAKE_PICURE_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
  }
```

Comment: Are your activity has launchMode="singleTask"?

Comment: @andreich I am calling startActivityForResult() from fragment, but parent activity for that fragment has launchMode="singleInstance".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. In my manifest my [<activity> element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element) had `launchMode="singleTask"`, but I changed said attribute value to `"singleTop"` and that solved the problem.

Comment: Please elaborate, exactly **where** do you set this property?

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my Poco X3 to Android 11 and now I have the same problem... It's probably a bug in MIUI (12.0.8). It works fine on other Android 11 devices.

Changing launchMode does not work. However when I detect a MIUI user I circumvent the chooser and just open the first camera app it finds.

Worst thing is that you can't really detect when this issue occurs. So you can't log when it goes wrong and therefore you can't find out which users are experiencing this issue.

The same issue also occurs when you try to get a photo from a gallery, or when you try to open a photo in a photo app. The latter results in a 'cannot find photo' message.